# picture background in my circle drawable. is it possible?

Tags: android

im my drawable circle.xml is it declared that

```
<solid
      android:color="#FFFF99"/>
```

is it possible that in my drawable the background is an image and not color? If possible, how?:)

Comment: really? how? i am having a hard time figuring out.

Comment: means are you just want to android:drawable="@drawable/imagehere"..... like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your drawable in a layered drawable, which has a bitmap drawable, with your circle drawable on top: [LayerList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList).

However, if you want to mask the image with the circle, that is a little more complicated: [use something like this](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/)